# Dynamic text format to decimal into a textbox c#

Tags: c#

I need to dynamically format a value entered by the user on a textbox.

for example :

```
textbox = "";
user enter = "1";
textbox = "0.01";
user enter = "12";
textbox = "0.12";
user enter = "123";
textbox = "1.23";
user enter = "123";
```

Any way to do that with `C#`?

Comment: Can't you try it yourself

Comment: Yes. What have you tried or make your question more specific. Start thinking about what happens if the user presses decimal point, back space highlights the .2 of 123 and presses 5. When we do this sort of thing we tend to show the unformatted version when you enter the box, and then format it on leave. However your idea would change the number and so make the UI hard to understand, and mean you would have to mess about with cut and copy. Personally I'd talk to  UX person, they are likely to raise an eyebrow. A lot of messing about just to round tow places and not press the . key....

Comment: Bad user experience - change the textbox that receives the input?

Comment: i know but on the device that runs this app it's the only way to do that.The . key it's in a very uncomfortable position

Answer (score 0):

Read some basic tutorials for c#. You should try something like this:

```
textBoxId.text= "" + Conver.ToInt32(textBoxId.text)/100;
```

Comment: Incorrect... You should Convert it to double and then to string() to make it work in c#

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
 textBoxId.Text= (Convert.ToDouble(textBoxId.text)/100).ToString();
```